# Java inheritance vs polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Do both inheritance and polymorphism constitute an IS-A relationship? And is it true that inheritance and "overriding" polymorphism happen in runtime while "overloading" polymorphism occurs in compile time? The reason I ask this is because a lot of forums seem to give conflicting and often confusing answers.

Thanks!

Comment: I think overloading has nothing to do with polymorphism.

Comment: Actually this is a form of pollymorphism: From Wikipedia: the term ad-hoc polymorphism to refer to polymorphic functions which can be applied to arguments of different types, but which behave differently depending on the type of the argument to which they are applied (also known as function overloading or operator overloading)..

Comment: @edalorzo:  factual accuracy of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad-hoc_polymorphism is  disputed.

Comment: @Jayan I think a proper reference is required for it, certainly I am not an expert on the field, but a simple search of "Ad hoc polymorphism" in Google Books provides many reputable references for overloading being considered a polymorphic feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your first part of the question I think [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) provides a good definition:

> In object-oriented programming, subtype polymorphism or inclusion
>   polymorphism is a concept in type theory wherein a name may denote
>   instances of many different classes as long as they are related by
>   some common super class. Inclusion polymorphism is generally
>   supported through subtyping, i.e., objects of different types are
>   entirely substitutable for objects of another type (their base
>   type(s)) and thus can be handled via a common interface.
>   Alternatively, inclusion polymorphism may be achieved through type
>   coercion, also known as type casting.

Another Wikipedia artile called [Polymorphism in object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) seems to answer your questions very well. The second reference in this article called [On Understanding Types, Data Abstraction, and Polymorphism](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/OnUnderstanding.A4.pdf) also covers this matters in great detail.

This subtyping feature in Java is achieved, among other means, through inheritance of classes and interfaces. Although the subtyping features of Java may not be evident in terms of inheritance all the time. Take for example the cases of covariance and contravariance with generics. Also, arrays are Serializable and Cloneable although this is not evident anywhere in the type hierarchy. It can also be said that through primitive widening conversion, also numeric types in Java are polymorphic. And operator behave polimorphically depending on their operands.

At any rate, inheritance plays an important role in the implementation of some of this polymorphism.

**Overloading vs Overriding**

Your second part of the question seems to be about choosing the implementation of a given method. Evidently, if a class overrides a method and you create an instance of that class you want the overriden version of method to be invoked, even if you are accessing the object through a reference of the parent class.

The selection of the *right implementation* of method is done at runtime as you well pointed out, now the signature of the method to be invoked is decided at compile time. Since overloading is about different methods with the same name and different signature, that is why it is said that overriding method selection happens at compile time.

**Overriding Method Selection at Compile Time**

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) (JLS) in section 15.12 [Method Invocation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) explains in detail the process that the compiler follows to choose the right method to invoke.

There, you will notice that this is a *compile-time* task. The JLS says in subsection 15.12.2:

> This step uses the **name of the method** and **the types of the argument expressions** 
>   to locate methods that are both accessible and applicable
>   There may be more than one such method, in which case the most specific one is chosen.

To verify the compile-time nature of this, you can do the following test.

Declare a class like this and compile it.

```
public class ChooseMethod {
   public void doSomething(Number n){
    System.out.println("Number");
   }
}
```

Declare a second class that invokes a method of the first one and compile it.

```
public class MethodChooser {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChooseMethod m = new ChooseMethod();
    m.doSomething(10);
   }
}
```

If  you invoke the main, the output says `Number`.

Now, add a second more specific *overloaded* method to the `ChooseMethod` class, and recompile it (but do not recompile the other class).

```
public void doSomething(Integer i) {
 System.out.println("Integer");
}
```

If you run the main again, the output is still `Number`.

Basically, because it was decided at compile time. If you recompile the `MethodChooser` class (the one with the main), and run the program again, the output will be `Integer`.

As such, if you want to force the selection of one of the overloaded methods, the type of the arguments must correspond with the type of the parameters at compile time, and not only at run time.

**Overriding Method Selection at Run time**

Again, the signature of the method is decided at compile time, but the actual implementation is decided at runtime.

Declare a class like this and compile it.

```
public class ChooseMethodA {
   public void doSomething(Number n){
    System.out.println("Number A");
   }
}
```

Then declare a second extending class and compile:

```
public class ChooseMethodB extends ChooseMethodA {  }
```

And in the MethodChooser class you do:

```
public class MethodChooser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChooseMethodA m = new ChooseMethodB();
        m.doSomething(10);
    }
}
```

And if you run it you get the output `Number A`, and this is Ok, because the method has not been overriden in `ChooseMethodB` and therefore the implementation being invoked is that of `ChooseMethodA`.

Now, add an overriden method in `MethodChooserB`:

```
public void doSomething(Number n){
    System.out.println("Number B");
}
```

And recompile just this one, and run the main method again.

Now, you get the output `Number B`

As such, the implementation was chosen at runtime, and not recompilation of the `MethodChooser` class was required.

Comment: The answer by Jayan is quite succinct, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Polymorphism: Ability of different objects to  receive same message and  respond  to differently.

Inheritance a way to achieve it, but not  necessary. See [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Overloading of a method is 'compile time syntax helper'- as  every method gets a unique signature after compilation.  Not really anything to do with polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is an effect of inheritance. It can only happen in classes that extend one another.

Polymorphism does happen at runtime; I've never heard of "overloading polymorphism".

Inheritance happens at compile time, the moment you write:

```
class A extends B
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right.

Polymorphism considers the runtime type of the object to decide wich method execute and the choice of which overloaded method to call is not dinamically decided at runtime, it depends on the types of the parameters at compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

Only inheritance constitute an IS-A relationship. polymorphism has nothing to do with it.

"overloading" is example of polymorphism. You can learn more about run-time and compile-time polymorphism [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Difference_between_runtime_and_compile_time_polymorphism)

Answer (score 0):

•   Inheritance defines parent-child relationship between two classes, polymorphism takes advantage of that relationship to add dynamic behavior in your code.

•   Inheritance encourages code reusability by allowing child class to inherit behavior from the parent class. On the other hand, Polymorphism allows the child to redefine already defined behavior inside the parent class. Without Polymorphism, it's not possible for a child to execute its own behavior while represented by a Parent reference variable, but with Polymorphism it can be done.

•   Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance of classes but allows multiple inheritance of Interface, which is actually required to implement Polymorphism. For example, a class can be Runnable, Comparator and Serializable at the same time because all three are interfaces. This makes them pass around in code e.g. you can pass an instance of this class to a method which accepts Serializable, or to Collections.sort() which accepts a Comparator.

•   Both Polymorphism and Inheritance allow Object-oriented programs to evolve. For example, by using Inheritance you can define new user types in an Authentication System and by using Polymorphism you can take advantage of the already written authentication code. Since, Inheritance guarantees minimum base class behavior, a method depending upon super class or super interface can still accept an object of the base class and can authenticate it.